# Javascript Mouseover Event Acting Squirrely

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to show a div container with child elements and just have the top portion of the container shown until the mouse moves over it and then show the entire container with the child elements with the content. This sorta works like I'm wanting it to, but the problem is that if you move the mouse over any of the child elements the entire main container slides back up and then slides back down again. I'm trying to make it so that the entire container slides down on MouseOver and stays down until MouseOut when it should slide back up.

```
<div onmouseover="$('#id_content').slideDown('fast', function(){ $(this).css('display', 'block'); $(this).css('visibility', 'visible'); });" 
 onmouseout="$('#id_content').slideUp('fast', function(){ $(this).css('display', 'none'); $(this).css('visibility', 'hidden'); });">
Title
<BR> 
mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm - hh:mm
<div id="id_content" style="visibility: hidden; display: none;">
    Description 
    <BR>
    Content 
</div>
<span class="commands"> <!-- Goes in the top right hand corner of the main container -->
    <span class="delete" onclick="delete_entry('record_id')">X</span>
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: If you set up a jsfiddle, you will most likely get more help.

Comment: i think you don't like to write jQuery separately :)

Comment: @bmorehokie Yeah, sorry about that. I keep forgetting to do that when I post.

Comment: @The-Val I'm not in the habit of it, but I'm realizing more and more than I need to. So the more code I write, the more I move that direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery has a function for that : [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/).

It also would allow you to avoid inlining the event handlers :

```
  <script>
    $('#a').hover(function(){
      $('#id_content').slideDown('fast', function(){ $(this).css('display', 'block'); $(this).css('visibility', 'visible'); });
    }, function(){
      $('#id_content').slideUp('fast', function(){ $(this).css('display', 'none'); $(this).css('visibility', 'hidden'); });
    });
  </script>
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/ipusad/1/edit)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! I guess my mindset really does need to get away from the old school methods such as "onmouseover".

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using JQuery anyway, so don't use onmouseover events.

Use the JQuery hover method instead: http://api.jquery.com/hover/

It allows you to provide a function when the mouse enters and object and when a mouse leaves an object.

Whilst youre at it I'd replace the onclick event with JQuerys .click() method. http://api.jquery.com/click/

Answer (score 0):

You want `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. They are combined by jQuery in `hover`.

In JavaScript you can detect when an `onmouseout` is an `onmouseleave` or whether you're just mousing over a child element. Check if `event.relatedTarget` is a child element.

Comment: I tried that as well, but seems as though that's a Microsoft exclusive thing. The jQuery hover did the trick in the end.

Comment: To my knowledge it works in all browsers. Here is the Firefox spec: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.relatedTarget